# Sentry on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sentry

I'm using Sentry to log some errors on Javascript but while using Internet Explorer  11 I'm getting `Syntax Error` while configuring the scope

```
function addSentryTag(key, value) {
    if (Sentry) {
       Sentry.configureScope(scope => { scope.setTag(key, value);})
    }
}
```

I assume the problem is using the lambda expression. Is there another way to add Tags to the scope?

Comment: What is a *lambda function*? If something called that would exist in Javascript, I surely don't know it.

Comment: sorry, lambda expression... is it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think IE11 supports the arrow syntax => are you running your code through any compilers like babel before trying it in the browser if not?

You can try this syntax:

```
function addSentryTag(key, value) {
if (Sentry) {
   Sentry.configureScope(function(scope) {
     scope.setTag(tag, value)
   })
}
```

}

Give it a go :)

Comment: Yes, that was what I need but unfortunately this was masking another error

Comment: 'Object doesn't support property or method 'assign''

Comment: Object.assign is also not in IE11 this is also another es6 method see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

To use these, run your code through a compiler like babel see:
https://babeljs.io/

Then you can do all the cool fancy stuff the rest of the kids are talking about :)

Answer (score 0):

The same code without the lambda function:

```
function addSentryTag(key, value) {
    if (Sentry) {
       Sentry.configureScope(function(scope){ 
         scope.setTag(key, value);
       });
    }
}
```